# Using multiple GPU's on a single Thrust function invocation

Tags: cuda, thrust

Can Thrust functions be made to use multiple-GPU's for their 
computations, if available? 
I have written this Thrust code which works just fine with a single 
GPU. (Tesla C2050) But I have three other Tesla C2050 cards attached 
to the machine which I would like to use for my computations.

I know that with multiple GPU's attached to a machine,  I can run one 
CUDA kernel per GPU in parallel i,e, kernel 0 on device 0, kernel 1 on 
device 1, etc.. 
But in my case I would like to use all the 4 GPU's on a single thrust 
function invocation like say thrust::sort. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Not Yet. But it is in Thrust's roadmap and you can express your wish in the Google group.
https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Roadmap

https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/131

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/thrust-users/qyP_oH7v58g

Also on the subject thinks Duane Merrill - the creator of the most rapid implementation of sorting (radix sort - b40c).